# Excel Data Validation - Pull cell info from one sheet to another with a data validation list

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

Is there a way to have specific cell in column B, Sheet3 be populated to Sheet1 cell C10 depending on what selection was selected on the Data Validation List(C5)?

I am not sure if I should be using the VLOOKUP or an IF/Then formula?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

You can use Index(Match) for this:

So in `c10` you would place:

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!C5,Sheet3!A:A,0))
```

If you would like to LOCK the reference cells because you will be copying/pasting this:

```
 =INDEX(Sheet3!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$C$5,Sheet3!$A:$A,0))
```

Where `Sheet3!B:B` is where you'd like to pull your answer from.

`Sheet1!C5` is the data validation list

`Sheet3!A:A` is the list of values that will `MATCH` to the value in the Data Validation List

Index(Match) is much more dynamic than vlookup.

Links with more explanation:

[Match Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

[Index Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)

Comment: Maybe I should explain this again.

Comment: Sheet 2 has a Validation data drop down list which is pulled from Sheet3 column A. When I select a specific item in the Validation list I want Sheet2 cell C10 to populate with adjacent cell data. Example: If I select the name "test1" on validation list on Sheet2 C5. Then Sheet2 C10 will auto populate with "issue1" which is pulled from (Sheet3 B1). If I select the name "test2" on validation list on Sheet2 C5. Then Sheet2 C10 will auto populate with "issue2" which is pulled from (Sheet3 B2).... and so forth